Vue watcher old value is always undefined
watch(() => route.params.id, (newId, oldId) => {
  console.log(newId, oldId, route.params.id) 
    if (newId && oldId != newId){
      documentsFromSelectedSource.value = []
      isNextPage.value = true
    }
},
{immediate: true})

This is how id is sent:
 router.push({name: 'somePath', params: {id: item.id}})

and this is the route itself:
path: "somePath/:id?"

The oldId is always undefined here. Route params id is good and newId is good. Also, bonus question- when I set immediate to false, nothing works neither for first nor subsequent requests. Thanks

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. It's unknown in which component the watcher is set and what is the exact sequence of route changes. What you describe could happen if you watch for it inside route view
